# How can i minimize database hits in this method

Tags: c#, linq

Inside the Service I have a method that is gathering data from different tables and combining it into a a single Dto, `accountDto`.

My biggest issue is that there are no foreign key relationships on the different tables. Thus I must create my own relationships.

The first two methods, `GetAccount` and `GetPerson` simply get data from single tables via Repository methods. The two tables are related by a common `TrinId`. The last method `GetRoleDtos` is a lot more complicated and involves multiple joins as shown below. This final bit of data is related by `AccountId`.

This single method seems to be hitting the database multiple times. How can I minimize the number of hits and improve speed, while following this same Service/Repository pattern?

```
    public AccountDto GetAccountDto(int accountId)
    {
        try
        {
            Account account = _unitOfWork.AccountRepository.GetAccount(accountId);

            AccountDto accountDto = account == null ? new AccountDto() : new AccountDto
            {
                AccountId = account.AccountId,
                UserName = account.UserName,
                TrinId = account.TrinId,
                LastName = account.LastName,
                FirstName = account.FirstName
            };

            Person person = _unitOfWork.AccountRepository.GetPerson(accountDto.TrinId);

        accountDto.Person = person == null ? new PersonDto() : new PersonDto
        {
            Id = person.Id,
            TrinId = person.TrinId,
            AccountId = person.AccountId,
            LastName = person.LastName,
            FirstName = person.FirstName,
            MiddleName = person.MiddleName,
            Gender = person.Gender,
            BirthDate = person.BirthDate
        };

        accountDto.Roles = _unitOfWork.AccountRepository.GetRoleDtos(accountId).ToList();

        return accountDto;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

---

```
public IQueryable<RoleDto> GetRoleDtos(int accountId)
    {
        var userModuleRoles = from account in _model.Accounts
                              join userRight in _model.UserRights on account.AccountId equals userRight.AccountId
                              join role in _model.Roles on userRight.RoleId equals role.Id
                              join organization in _model.Organizations on userRight.OrganizationId equals organization.Id
                              join module in _model.Modules on role.ModuleId equals module.Id
                              where (account.IsApproved == true && userRight.Status == 1 && account.AccountId == accountId)
                              select new RoleDto
                              {
                                  Id = role.Id,
                                  RoleName = role.Name,
                                  AccountId = account.AccountId,
                                  OrganizationId = organization.Id,
                                  OrganizationName = organization.Name,
                                  ModuleId = module.Id,
                                  ModuleName = module.Name
                              };

        return userModuleRoles;
    }
```

---

Here was my original attempt at an all in one query. It worked but I was having trouble getting the `List<RoleDto>`. How can I also get a list of the Role Dto?

The query I'm using now is shown in the `GetRoleDtos` method but it would need to be included in this query. I did have one partially working solution but its deleted now. I abandoned it because when there were no RoleDto records the entire query was returning null. In this case I would still need a populated AccountDto with an empty collection of RoleDto. I believe I need to use `DefaultIfEmpty` to get and empty collection, but it was at this point I gave up because the query was getting unwieldy. :-(

```
        return account;
    }

    public AccountDto GetAccountDto(int accountId)
    {
        return (from a in _model.Accounts
                       join p in _model.People on a.TrinId equals p.TrinId into perJoin
                       from per in perJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       where a.AccountId == accountId
                       select new AccountDto
                       {
                           AccountId = a.AccountId,
                           UserName = a.UserName,
                           TrinId = a.TrinId,
                           LastName = a.LastName,
                           FirstName = a.FirstName,
                           Person = new PersonDto
                                {
                                    Id = per.Id,
                                    LastName = per.LastName,
                                    FirstName = per.FirstName,
                                    MiddleName = per.MiddleName,
                                    Gender = per.Gender,
                                    BirthDate = per.BirthDate
                                }
                       }).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a new object to return from your repository. This new object would be something like, and this is just an incomplete idea:

```
public class AccountInfo {
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int TrinId { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public Person PersonInfo { get; set; }
    public List<Roles> AccountRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a single method in your repository that populates all of the necessary properties, since you can clearly get the `Account` and the `List<Roles>` based on `accountId`, and then join to your person info based on that `TrinId`. I'll leave the query up to you.

Comment: Solid answer, I find many people feel when using a service/repository, that each repository should only ever return the single object that the repository is built for. Whereas in reality it would be very unmanageable and inefficient to build a system that strictly adheres to that.

Comment: Yeah i originally started to try something like this, but the query got complicated real fast...

Comment: @navig8tr that's fine on the names. I assume your `Person` class would have first and last names in it. Just populate those from your query as well.

Comment: I included my first attempt at an all inclusive query. I named it the class `AccountDto` rather than `AccountInfo` but the idea is the same.

Comment: @navig8tr I think you're getting into question-scope-creep. Your initial question of `How can I minimize the number of hits and improve speed, while following this same Service/Repository pattern?` was answered. The query itself sounds like a different one.